# When should I tag a revision in Mercurial

Tags: mercurial, tags

Could anyone give me any guidelines on when I might want to tag a revision in Mercurial.

For instance would it be a good idea to use them to mark points at which my application gets uploaded?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- When you release/deploy, it is a nice idea to tag.
- When you just want a bookmark for yourself, you can use a local tag.
- When you need to specify a specific revision, for example in a bug report or an email, simply use the changeset id, it is long but you can shorten it.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a non exhaustive list of when you might want to tag your code:

- When you deploy it on an environment
- When your Continuous Integration pass successfully a set of quality tests
- When a feature is integrated and complete
- When the acceptance tests are successfully ended.

You may think that you'll end up with a lot of tags (and that's true), but it really helps to track the status of you development and to avoid that things go wild.

Answer (score 1):

At our company we use tags when we deploy our applications to our servers.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's a good practice to tag a codebase when it's released and you might want to tag it too at the end of a sprint / development cycle.

Answer (score 1):

Tagging on releases is what the Mercurial project itself does:

https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/StandardBranching

you can see the results here:

https://www.mercurial-scm.org/repo/hg/tags